# Can holes be the object of burning?

Tags: vocabulary

> Neville had somehow managed to melt Seamus's cauldron into a twisted
>   blob, and their potion was seeping across the stone floor, **burning
>   holes** in people's shoes.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

There is a tricky word, holes, after *burning*. If holes is the object of *burning*, it’s semantically somewhat strange. If not, holes seems to be the result of burning. How can I understand the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The potion is very acidic, and reacts when contacting people's clothing. When acid melts through something and destroys it, we can refer to that as *burning holes* in something. I suppose technically nothing is being burned (or maybe it is, I suppose that's a chemistry question!) but the acid is "eating" through the material of their shoes and leaving holes behind. So *burning holes* is an acceptable way to describe what the potion is doing to their shoes.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Acid+burn), two definitions which support the *acid can burn* aspect as well as the idea that *holes can be burnt*:

> **burn** *v.tr.*
>
> 3) To damage or injure by fire, heat, radiation, electricity, or a caustic agent: *burned the toast; burned my skin with the acid.*
>
> 5.
>   a. To make or produce by fire or heat: *burn a hole in the rug.*

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in this sentence, "holes" is not the object of "burning". Instead, "burning" is used as a [linking verb](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/linking-verb.html), and the noun phrase "holes in people's shoes" is the subject [complement](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/complterm.htm) that completes the predicate.

Thus, the holes are not themselves on fire, but are created through the act of burning.

Comment: Before meeting WendiKidd’s answer, I thought that burning could be a link-like verb and holes may be a resultaive adjective. But subject complement? When you said it, which word do you think is the subject?

Comment: @Listenever: The _subject_ of that part of the sentence is "potion". The _subject component_ is "holes". The subject component is associated with a linking verb (see the link in my answer).